# int auth(){stuff}; auth(); ERROR: expected initializer brefore int

Tags: c++, authentication

EDIT: I started from scratch, going with a user+pass authentication for better security.
I posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770713/username-and-password-check-c).

I'm writing a program that checks that the computer running it has a specific hostname (as an authentication method).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void RUN()
{
//Do stuff
}

char const* HOSTNAME
int auth()
{
   if (HOSTNAME = getenv("HOSTNAME")) 
   {
      HOSTNAME = getenv("HOSTNAME");
      return 0;
   }
   else if(HOSTNAME = getenv("COMPUTERNAME"))
   {
       HOSTNAME = getenv("COMPUTERNAME");
       return 0;
   }
   else
   {
       return 1;
   };
}




int main()
{
   cout << "Authenticating..." << endl; auth();
   if (HOSTNAME == "Craptop")
   {
      cout << "Success!" << endl;
      RUN();
   }
   else
   {
      cout << 
      cout << "Authentication failed! Exiting..." << endl;
      exit(0);
   };
   return 0;
}
```

Im getting this error: (should be the initializer but seams to act like a variable)

```
./EX_host_locked.cpp:5:1: error: expected initializer before ‘int’
 int auth()
 ^~~
```

since int acts like a variable, auth is uninitialized and causing more errors later.

How can I make int be the initializer for auth? Also how could I generally improve my code (for security/stability)?

Comment: Relying on the hostname of the machine for authentication is a *really* bad idea. It can easily be faked (and is not even guaranteed to be unique).

Comment: I know. It's not meant to be released to the public, just my friends(they're just average users) because stuff in RUN() might be different for each computer. This is to ensure that only the right copy can run on each pc.

Comment: Fair enough. What would be a better solution?

Comment: "What would be a better solution?" - actually checking some real credentials; like a username+password, something signed with a specific private key - you know, something that's *not* just a random attribute of the computer that can be easily manipulated to be whatever you want.

Comment: I'm doing just a password(So far I haven't been able to figure out a user+pass combo but security is not the point just to do the right thing for the right pc)

Comment: `if (HOSTNAME == "Craptop")` That's *not* going to compare string equivalence; it will compare *pointer* equivalence, and will with near-certainty *always* be false. If you're going to code in C++, then use the C++ standard library (such as `std::string`) if you want to use such syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing ; after line following line:

```
 char const* HOSTNAME
```

So you are getting the error. Put ; and make it:

```
 char const* HOSTNAME;
```