# username and password check

Tags: c++, authentication

I'm writting a program (mostly educational purpose but if I like it then I'll probably use it in a larger project later) for username + password authentication. What I have so far "works", meaning there are no errors, but it does behave a little weirdly. It did STUFF() about 9 times (I didn't save the exact output) before exiting when it's only meant to do it once.

How can I make it do STUFF() just once? How can I make the password input invisible? And how can I just generally improve security/syntax or make it shorter?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void STUFF()
{
   cout << "Doing stuff..." << endl;
}

int CREDS;
void AUTH()
{
   cout << "Username: "; string USER; cin >> USER;
   cout << "Password: "; string PASS; cin >> PASS;
   if (USER == "josh" and PASS == "passwd")
   {
      CREDS = 0;
   }
   else 
   {
      CREDS = 1;
   };
}

void RETRY()
{
   cout << "Authentication failed! Try again? [Y/n]" << endl; char REPLY; cin >> REPLY;
   if (REPLY == 'Y' or REPLY == 'y')
   {
      AUTH();
   }
   else if (REPLY == 'N' or REPLY == 'n')
   {
      cout << "Exiting..." << endl;
   }
   else
   {
      RETRY();
   };
}

int main()
{
   AUTH();
   if (CREDS == 0)
   {
      STUFF();
      return 0;
   }
   else if (CREDS == 1)
   {
      RETRY();
   };

}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/EPnGn4

Comment: Also, your RETRY code isn't going to behave as you expect. It won't loop back so even if you enter "Y" the program will exit.

Comment: I tested again (making it a point to get user and pass wrong to retry). choosing no exited and choosing yes then getting them right just exited without doing stuff. EDIT: reproduced that outcome two more times then got the user/pass correct the 1st time and it printed "auth failed! try again?" exactly 9 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have abandoned that last program and wrote this from scratch. 
For anyone new to C++ that would like to use this, it is licensed under the GNU GPLv2 and can be found in [Small-Projects-Cpp](https://github.com/Myersj281/Small-Projects-Cpp) on Github. Just download "Userpass.zip" as it is not necessary to clone the entire repository.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
```

getpass() makes the password input show asterisks. Not exactly invisible, but it's probably the best solution for that.

```
using namespace std;
string PASSWD;
string getPASS()
{
    termios oldt;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    termios newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    string PASS;
    cout << "Password: "; cin >> PASS; cout << endl;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
    return PASS;
   }
```

MENU() has a switch/case menu but it is unrelated so i'm skipping it in the asnwer. You can replace it with whatever funtions you want.

```
int attempts = 0;
int main()
{

   while (attempts == 3)
   {
      cout << "Too many attempts have been made! Exiting..." << endl; exit(0);
   };
   string USER;
   cout << "Username: "; cin >> USER;

   if (USER == "josh") 
       {   
           if (getPASS() == "hsoj")
       {
        cout << "\nAccess granted!\n" << endl;
        MENU();
       }
           else
       {
           cout << "\nAccess denied!\n" << endl; 
        attempts = attempts + 1;
        main();
       };
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "\nAccess denied!\n" << endl; 
      attempts = attempts + 1;
      main();
   };
   return 0;
}
```